# Youtube Downloading Progress bar issue

Tags: python, download, youtube, progress-bar, pytube

I am trying to add download progress while dowloading a Youtube video, 
However every method I try, something weird issue comes up. 
Can anyone help?

Issue is 
TypeError: progress_func() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'file_handle' and 'bytes_remaining'

I have tried supplying None value to each but then it goes on to saying that bytes_remaining & size are not of the same type.

Thank you

```
def progress_func(self, stream, chunk, file_handle,bytes_remaining):
  size = self.video.filesize
  progress = (float(abs(bytes_remaining-size)/size))*float(100)
  self.loadbar.setValue(progress)

yurl = input("VURL here: ")
yt = YouTube(yurl, on_progress_callback=progress_func)
```

Comment: `progress_func` seems to be a method of a class. Most probably `YouTube`. Could you please provide more of your code? Please read [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Sure here it is 

from pytube import YouTube

def progress_func(self, stream, chunk, file_handle,bytes_remaining):
  size = self.video.filesize
  progress = (float(abs(bytes_remaining-size)/size))*float(100)
  self.loadbar.setValue(progress)

yurl = input("VURL here: ")
yt = YouTube(yurl, on_progress_callback=progress_func)
yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').first().download()
print("\n Downloaded")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The on_progress_callback function just needs 3 parameters: stream, chunk and bytes_remaining. Also, it looks like that function is a method inside a class: in that case, you have to manually pass the "self" argument using a lambda function, so your code should look like this:

```
yt = YouTube(yurl, on_progress_callback=lambda stream, chunk, bytes_remaining: self.progress_func(self, stream, chunk, bytes_remaining))
```

I ran into the same issue a while ago and this is how I fixed it. Hope this will be your solution aswell!